# PHP - Wordpress post loop not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, blogs

I'm having trouble with the Blog portion of my project I'm working on. I have made a new template and pointed the Blog page to that template but no posts show up on the page. I have also went under Reading > and changed the Posts Page to Blog, the whole page doesn't show up. Below is the code and a link:

http://www.hbaofwashingtoncounty.org/hbawc2014/blog/

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Blog
*/
;?>

<?php get_header();?>
<div class="inner">
    <!-- Content Section Start -->
    <div class="contentsec-new twocol">
        <!-- Top Header Start -->
        <div class="topheader">
            <div class="inner"> 
                <!-- Logo Start --> 
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url();?>">
                        <?php if($logo_img = $_extracoding->set_value('LOGO', get_template_directory_uri().'/images/logo.png', true)): ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo $logo_img;?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name');?>" id="logo" />
                        <?php else:?>
                            <span class="logo">&nbsp;</span>
                        <?php endif;?>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <!-- Logo End --> 
                <!-- Right Header Start -->
                <div class="righthead">
                    <div class="topsec"> 
                        <!-- Service Time and Search Start -->

                        <!-- Service Time and Search End --> 
                        <!-- Top Navigation Start -->
                        <div class="menuwrapper">
                            <?php $redirectTo = (is_home() || is_front_page()) ? home_url() : $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>

                            <?php if( ! is_user_logged_in()): ?>

                                <ul class="topnavi" style="float:right;">
                                    <li><a href="javascript:animatedcollapse.toggle('loginbox')"><?php _e('Member Login', 'heavens_corner');?></a> 
                                        <!-- Login Bubble Start -->
                                        <div id="loginbox"> <span class="logintop">&nbsp;</span>
                                            <div class="logincenter">
                                                <h3 class="white bold upper"><?php _e('User Login', 'heavens_corner');?></h3>
                                                <form action="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/wp-login.php" method="post" name="loginform" id="loginform">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><h5 class="white"><?php _e('User Name', 'heavens_corner');?></h5></li>
                                                    <li><input name="log" type="text" class="bar" /></li>
                                                    <li><h5 class="white"><?php _e('Password', 'heavens_corner');?></h5></li>
                                                    <li><input  name="pwd" type="password" class="bar" /><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $redirectTo;?>" name="redirect_to" /></li>
                                                    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword" class="forgot"><?php _e('Forget Password?', 'heavens_corner');?></a> </li>
                                                    <li class="nopading"><input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Sign in Now', 'heavens_corner');?>" class="button backcolr" /></li>
                                                </ul>
                                                </form>
                                            </div>
                                            <span class="loginbottom">&nbsp;</span> </div>
                                        <!-- Login Bubble End --> 
                                    </li>
                                </ul>

                            <?php else:?>
                            <ul class="topnavi" style="float:right;">
                                <li><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( $redirectTo );?>"><?php _e('Logout', 'heavens_corner');?></a> 
                            </ul>
                            <?php endif;?>

                            <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'top-menu', 'container'=>false, 'menu_class'=>'topnavi')); //Top menu?>
                        <br />
                        <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'main-menu', 'container'=>false, 'menu_class'=>'subnavi')); //Top menu?>

                        </div>
                        <!-- Top Navigation End --> 
                    </div>
                    <ul class="boxed">
                            <?php get_template_part('modules/top_links');?>
                            <!-- Search Start -->
                            <li class="last">
                                <?php echo get_search_form(); //Search form ?>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Search End -->
                        </ul>
                    <div class="clear"></div>

                    <?php if($header_settings = get_option(THEME_PREFIX.'general_settings')):?>
                    <!--Header Short Text-->
                    <div class="watchlive">
                        <h3><?php echo character_limiter(kvalue($header_settings, 'header_text'), 50);?></h3>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </div>
                <!-- Right Header End --> 
            </div>
        </div>      
        <!-- Bread Crumb Start -->
        <div class="breadcrumb" style="margin-top:24px;">
            <?php echo get_the_breadcrumb(); ?>
        </div>
        <!-- Bread Crumb End -->
        <!-- Sub Page Banner Start -->
        <div class="subbanner">
            <?php fw_top_banner('category'); //Get big header image?>
        </div>
        <!-- Sub Page Banner End -->
        <!-- Column 3 Start -->
        <div class="col3 border-right left">
            <!-- Blog Start -->
            <div class="blog">
                <h1 class="heading colr"><?php single_cat_title();?></h1>
                <!-- Blog Post Start -->
                <div class="post noborder nopading">
                  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                      <div class="post-date backcolr">
                          <span><?php echo get_the_date('j');?></span>
                          <span><?php echo get_the_date('M');?></span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="post-heading">
                          <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="colr"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                      </div>
                      <div class="clear"></div>
                      <?php if($media = fw_post_video('w=667&h=369&showThumb=1&thumbSize=category-featured')):?>
                      <div class="post-thumb">
                         <?php echo $media;?>
                      </div>
                      <?php endif;?>

                      <div class="post-feat">
                          <ul>
                              <li class="authore"><?php _e('by,', 'heavens_corner');?> <a href="<?php the_author_link();?>"><?php the_author();?></a></li>
                              <li class="comments"><a href="<?php comments_link();?>"><?php comments_number();?></a></li>
                              <?php if(has_tag()):?><li class="tags"><?php the_tags();?></li><?php endif;?>
                          </ul>
                      </div>
                      <div class="clear"></div>
                      <div class="post-desc">
                          <p><?php echo (function_exists('the_exerpt')) ?  get_the_exerpt() : character_limiter(get_the_content(),450,'',true);?></p>
                          <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="readmore txthover"><?php _e('Keep Reading', 'heavens_corner');?></a>
                      </div>
                  <?php endwhile; ?>

                </div>
                <!-- Blog Post End -->
                <!-- Pagination Start -->
                <?php if($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1):?>
                <div class="paginations">
                    <ul><?php fw_blog_pagination(); ?></ul>
                </div>
                <?php endif;?>
                <!-- Pagination End -->
            </div>
            <!-- Blog End -->
        </div>
        <!-- Column 3 End -->
        <!-- Column 1 Start -->
        <div class="col1 right">
            <!-- Widget Start -->
               <?php fw_dynamic_sidebars('category', get_query_var('cat'));?>
            <!-- Widget End -->
        </div>
        <!-- Column 1 End -->
    </div>
    <!-- Content Section End -->
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<!-- Footer Start -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You should take a look at the source of your page, you have an error causing php to stop. Check the server log and / or enable error displaying on your page.

Comment: add this to the top of the page to show errors `error_reporting(E_ALL);`
. Also remove the ; in the template page name declaration.

Comment: Even though all the other pages work?

Comment: I turned on error checking and looking at the log, anything in particular I should be looking for?